# how can i pass alot of data from viewController to another on without using segue?

Tags: arrays, swift, delegates, protocols, nsnotificationcenter

I want to pass a UIimage from viewController to another without using segue and i keep searching for this problem for weeks. Also, i tried to do it using notificationCenter, delegate and protocol but it didn't work with me so help please.

This is a screenShot describe what i want to do exactly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bE4F.png)

Also, this is my code for the viewController which i want to pass the thor image from it when the pass Label button is clicked .

```
            import UIKit

  protocol UserChosePhoto {
  func userHasChosen(image: UIImage)
  }


class passingDataViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var image1: UIImageView!

var image: UIImage? = nil
  var delegate: UserChosePhoto? = nil




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
  image1.image = image
   
    
    
   
}

@IBAction func passLabel(_ sender: Any) {
    
    
   func tapped() {
       if (delegate != nil) {
           self.delegate!.userHasChosen(image: image1.image!)
       }
 
 
}

}
}
```

and this is the code for the viewController which i want to display thor image in it .

```
   import UIKit


   class receivingDataViewController: UIViewController, UserChosePhoto {



   @IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!
  
   @IBOutlet var image2: UIImageView!

   var usedImage: UIImage? = nil




   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    
  
    
   }



   func userHasChosen(image: UIImage) {
       usedImage = image
    print("delegation: \(image)")
    
   }
    
    
    


}
```

Comment: how you go from `passingDataViewController` to `receivingDataViewController` ? you need to set delegate

Comment: @jawadAli how can i do it? im new in swift also mister Ali please help me because i keep searching alot for this, what i want exactly is to pass the label and the image from many viewControllers to TableViewCell because im building a shop application and i want to pass it to the cart tableViewCell so, help me please.

Comment: @jawadAli please help mister Ali, at lease i want pass only the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using public variable. It will let you store anything you want in it and access it from anywhere in your project.
for example, put this line anywhere outside of any class:

```
public var userImage: UIImage? = nil
```

and then you can use it **anywhere** in your code by using `userImage` like any other variable.

Or, if you have multiple variables, you can create a struct with static variables:

```
struct sharedVariables {
    static var userImage: UIImage? = nil
    static var userList: [Any] = [64, "Hello, world!"]
    static var integer: Int = 300
    // Or add anything you want; just make sure to start with 'static'
}
```

And then you can use the variables in the struct like that:

```
sharedVariables.userList
```

Of course, there are more ways to do what you asked for, but this is the simplest one.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work :(  do you have twitter to show you everything i did ?

Comment: Apologies for downvoting your answer. Read my answer - particularly the last note - to understand why I think this is not a useful answer. Delegation is the right route to go, not public variables - wherever it's declared.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. But your way is unnecessary complicated. Another way to go with my answer is by creating a struct with static variables (that's what I'm doing in my projects, and so far it's working great). So I still don't understand why creating a protocol in this complicated way is better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing a few things missing, along with some Swift coding conventions not being followed. So let's start with your `UserChosePhoto` protocol, which is pretty good. But - why not make your code readable?

```
protocol PassingDataViewControllerDelegate {
      func userHasChosen(image: UIImage)
}
```

Sure, what you have will work, but adding *Delegate* to the end of your name (along with which VC you are using this with) make everyone know what you are doing.

Now you need to properly set up your first view controller:

```
class PassingDataViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: PassingDataViewControllerDelegate? = nil
    func tapped() {
        if (delegate != nil) {
           self.delegate!.userHasChosen(image: image1.image!)
        }
    }
}
```

Again, *very* close to your code - I just capitalized your view controller's class name. This is how Swift coders do it. Oh, and since I changed the name of the portal, that needed to be changed to.

But there's one more thing - you have a **second** way to code this:

```
class PassingDataViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: PassingDataViewControllerDelegate! = nil
    func tapped() {
        delegate.userHasChosen(image: image1.image)
    }
}
```

This results in a couple of things. Obviously, the delegate call is simpler. But more importantly, if you don't set up things correctly in your second view controller, your app crashes. (Sometimes, that's actually a good thing!)

Here's where I think you didn't do things right - the second VC:

```
class ReceivingDataViewController: UIViewController, PassingDataViewControllerDelegate {

    var usedImage: UIImage? = nil
    let passingDataViewController = PassingDataViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        passingDataViewController.delegate = self    
    }
    func userHasChosen(image: UIImage) {
        usedImage = image
        print("delegation: \(image)")
    }
}
```

Now, several things.

First, note that I'm creating an *instance* of the first VC - that's needed. Delegation is always a 1:1 kind of communication. What is *still* missing (because you haven't mentioned it in your question) is *how* the first VC is being presented. I know you don't want to use a segue, but how is your app "flow" going from the first to the second view controller? Usually without a segue that means presenting it modally (like you would with `UIImagePickerController`). You can also add both the view controller and it's view as a child VC and view in the hierarchy.

Second, I'm telling the first VC that the second VC is the it's delegate. If instead of using optionals (`var delegate: PassingDataViewControllerDelegate? = nil`) you force-unwrap things (`var delegate: PassingDataViewControllerDelegate! = nil`) you'd see your app crash because the second VC isn't the delegate for the first VC without `passingDataViewController.delegate = self`.

FINAL NOTE:

While I was writing this @TLG_Codin provided an answer. It *could* work - but *where is `userImage` declared as a public variable? In one of two places:

- Globally, as in outside of a class. That's called a *singleton*, and be very, very careful on doing this. Since it's global, *anyplace* in your app can change it. That's why singletons are generally frowned upon.
- Inside your first VC. The problem there is - how are you presenting this VC? Again, you've mentioned you don't want to use a segue. So... you're back to my note about presenting the first VC from the second or adding the VC and it's view to the hierarchy. Either way? Delegation works perfectly, and at the *moment* you wish to tell interested classes (in this case the second VC) that `userImage` has changed, you do.